# How to give an instance variable access to an 'id' in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a "userinfos_controller" where user stores their information. They also can upload a video to their profile. I am showing this video under the show method in the userinfos_controller as shown below. I want the '@myvideo" to get the video associated with the user. When a user deletes their video and re-upload, the video_id changes. So I can't call that video using the video_id. Is there a way to call Video.userinfo.last? I don't want to call Video.last, because it'll give me the last video uploaded across all users, not just the last video uploaded by that particular user. You can also see in my rails console, the video has a user_id, userinfo_id and a video_id. So right now, under my show method, when I do:

```
def show
    @myvideo = Video.find(params[:userinfo_id])
end
```

It looks for Video_id that is equal to userinfo_id, while I want it to look for the last video uploaded by that particular user/userinfo.

My id relationships(please right click and open in new tab to see more clearly):[image]

My userinfos controller:

```
class UserinfosController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_userinfo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
      @userinfors = Userinfo.all
      @myvideo = Video.all
    end

    def show
        @myvideo = Video.find(params[:userinfo_id])
    end

    def new
        @userinformation = current_user.userinfos.build
    end

    def create
        @userinformation = current_user.userinfos.build(userinfo_params)
        if @userinformation.save
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
        @userinformation.destroy
        redirect_to userinfo_path
    end

    private
        def userinfo_params
            params.require(:userinfo).permit(:name, :email, :college, :gpa, :major)
        end

        def find_userinfo
            @userinformation = Userinfo.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

Show video view:

```
<div>
    <%= video_tag @myvideo.introvideo_url.to_s, :size => "480x320", :controls =>true %>
</div>
```

Video model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :userinfo
    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :introvideo, VideoUploader 
end
```

Userinfo model:

```
class Userinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :videos
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vidoes
  has_many :userinfos
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

My migrations that show all the id's added:
[image]

My routes:[image]

Comment: Add the relationships in your models, the image is really difficult to understand.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Sorry about that. I added the migrations and the model. If you are talking about not being able to see the rails console pic clearly, please right click and open in new tab. It will look better there.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SebastiánPalma some help here, buddy? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292947/how-to-send-user-to-their-profile-as-soon-as-they-sign-in/44293213#44293213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create a direct association between User and Video - or make it indirect through a join model. Don't do both.

Direct 1-n:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :videos
  has_many :user_infos
  # ...
end

class Video < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  # ...
end

class UserInfo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :videos, through: :user
end
```

Indirect 1-n:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_infos
  has_many :videos, through: :user_infos
  # ...
end

class UserInfo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :videos
end

class Video < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_info
  has_one :user, through: :user_info
  # ...
end
```

Both will let you do:

```
@user.videos.last
@user_info.videos.last
```

---

```
def show
  @my_video =  @user_info.videos.order(created_at: :desc).last
end
```

Comment: The idomatially correct ruby naming is `UserInfo` and `user_info`.

Comment: The reason you don't want to do both is that you are duplicating the foreign keys and when you use the associations in ActiveRecord it will only populate one foreign key.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was adding all what you said to my code and it worked! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I'm not sure why, but I have two users that have uploaded two videos. In chrome, one video can be played, the other cannot. In IE,both works well. lol

Comment: Please check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221502/how-to-send-users-to-different-paths-according-to-information-entered-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but I think you want to access the Video that your user previously uploaded, after it uploaded the new one.
Assuming you have a has_many :videos relationship set up on the User model, you can do this:

```
@user.videos.order(created_at: :desc).second
```

Or if you don't have the user instance and just have user_id.

```
Video.where(userinfo_id: params[:userinfo_id]).order(created_at: :desc).second
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Or maybe you just want to access the latest users video. Again, I don't know how you set up your relations. I am assuming user can have many videos.

```
Video.where(userinfo_id: params[:userinfo_id]).order(created_at: :desc).first
```

Or shorter

```
Video.where(userinfo_id: params[:userinfo_id]).last
```

Comment: Hey buddy, yeah, thats exactly what I want. I just want the last video the user uploaded. The user can only have one video. And I have updated the question with my models so you can see the relationship. What exactly is 'some_id"?

Comment: it's the user_info_id, just substitute it with params[:userinfo_id]. Oh, and you have to search Video by userinfo_id, I see that you added relations to your question. So Video.where(userinfo_id: params[:userinfo_id]).last. I'll update answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I went with Max's answer and it worked! Please check this out too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221502/how-to-send-users-to-different-paths-according-to-information-entered-in-rails

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`ActiveRecord#last`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last):

```
def show
  @myvideo = Video.where('userinfo_id = ?', params[:userinfo_id]).last
end
```

That will give you the videos uploaded to `userinfo` with `id` equal to `params[:userinfo_id]` taking the last record.

Comment: Hey, it gives me the following error:

| 
  
  C:/Users/dinuka/Desktop/Railsapps/knowmenew/app/views/userinfos/show.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `introvideo_url' for nil:NilClass.        |

I have updated my question to include my show view so you know were the "intro_video" comes from.

Comment: Doesn't it work with `introvideo` instead `introvideo_url `?

Comment: No it does not. introvideo_url is the one that  works because in my index view,I am showing all the available videos from all the users and the videos show up on that view.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood, check the value for `@myvideo` before printing, check isn't giving you a `nil` element.

Comment: also paste the output of running "rake routes | grep video"

Comment: To check that, I did "<% @myvideo %>" in my index view, no error, but only the navbar and footer shows up. No info displayed. Then I did "<%=@myvideo %>" and in the body, this showed up: #<Video::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000bd16d88>. Not as an error message, just as text.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma I updated the question with the routes

Comment: You're getting an `ActiveRecord_Relation`, how are you declaring the `@myvideo` variable you're working with?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma hey man. Thanks a LOT for trying to help me. I tried max's solution and it worked.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma check this out please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221502/how-to-send-users-to-different-paths-according-to-information-entered-in-rails