# How to send users to different paths according to information entered in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My userinfos controller handles user information. As soon as the user signs up, I want them to go to the page that lets them fill out the user information like name, email, gpa, college...Lets just say they leave before completing the form, when they sign in again, I want to check if the user information has been filled out, if not, I want to take them to enter the new information page. What should I do to make that happen? I was told to add this code to the application

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        if @userinformation.Userinfo.count.zero?
            new_userinfo_path
        else
            root_path
        end
    end

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        if @userinformation.Userinfo.count.zero?
            new_userinfo_path
        else
            root_path
        end
    end

end
```

But it doesn't work. Since "@userinformation" is an instance variable in the userinfos controller, and it's not related to the application controller, it doesn't work. I know the code is wrong in the above controller, but that's the logic I want. If there count of data in the Userinfo model of the particular user is 0, then I want to direct them to the "new_userinfo_path".

My Userinfo controller:

```
class UserinfosController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_userinfo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
      @userinfors = Userinfo.all
      @myvideo = Video.all
    end

    def show
      @myvideo = @userinformation.videos.last
    end

    def new
        @userinformation = current_user.userinfos.build
    end

    def create
        @userinformation = current_user.userinfos.build(userinfo_params)
        if @userinformation.save
          redirect_to userinfo_path(@userinformation)
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @userinformation.update(userinfo_params)
            redirect_to userinfo_path(@userinformation)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @userinformation.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private
        def userinfo_params
            params.require(:userinfo).permit(:name, :email, :college, :gpa, :major)
        end

        def find_userinfo
            @userinformation = Userinfo.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

Userinfo model:

```
class Userinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :videos, through: :user

    def info_complete?
        name? && email? && college? && gpa? && major?
    end
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :userinfos
  has_many :videos

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Please tell me if you guys need anymore information to understand the question better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what I would do is instead of trying to count an instance object, I'd go to the userInfo model and create a method to check this. Would be something like this:

```
def info_complete?
  name? && email? && college? && gpa? && major?
end
```

So now you've got a method that will return false unless all the fields in userInfo have a value (.e.g the form isn't complete and we should redirect them there).

So now we can go back to `after_sign_in_path` method and query the `resource`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # I'm not too sure how userInfo relates to a user in your app
    if resource.userinfo.info_complete?
      redirect_to root_path
    else 
      redirect_to new_userinfo_path
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, I added the above code and I get the following error:
"NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create:.....undefined method `userinfo' for #<User:0x0000000deefb08> Did you mean? userinfos userinfos=". The "userinfo" they are talking about is the userinfo in "if resource.userinfo.info_complete?" which is in the application controller. I also added the code of my models so you can see how they relate to each other. Thanks

Comment: This won't work since the assocation is `has_many :userinfos`.

Comment: Thanks for posting your model, comparing my solution to Max's. The only difference is I have `redirect_to new_user_info_path` and he has `new_userinfo_path`. I've edited my answer to reflect this now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the association between User and Userinfo to check if the user has any `user_infos`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        if resource.userinfos.empty?
            new_userinfo_path
        else
            root_path
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: PS. I would really encourage you to fix the naming issues in your application before you go on. https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, Max! It worked. I will definitely look into the naming

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply redirect the user in your `SignUpController` or `SignInController` actions?

```
class SignUpController < ApplicationController
  // ...

  def create
    // Sign up... the user probably won't have any userinfos yet.
    redirect_to new_userinfo_path
  end

  // ...
end


class SignInController < ApplicationController
  // ...

  def create
    // Sign up... the user probably won't have any userinfos yet.
    if @userinformation.userinfo.count.zero?
      redirect_to new_userinfo_path
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  // ...
end
```

Comment: Hey Tobias, are you suggesting I make two different controllers for these two different actions? Right now, I'm using Devise for authentication. So I don't have these controllers already made.

Comment: @Dinukaperera Oh didn't notice that you're using Devise. I'm not using it a lot. Then you are fine with your solution but instead of using the instance variable use the resource parameter which is passed to the method. You can also use your [custom controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) if you want.